# Why is this bounce counter not updating and creating an infinite loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

The bounce counter is not updating and in turn the bounce height is not updating. This is leading to an infinite while loop

```
def bounce_counter (drop_height, minimum_height, energy_loss):
    bounce = 0
    bounce_height = drop_height*(energy_loss**bounce)
    number_of_bounces = bounce - 1
    while bounce_height > minimum_height:
        bounce = bounce + 1
```

My inputs are all floated numbers and if I set the initial drop height less than the minimum height then an else statement breaks the loop immediately.

Comment: In your own words, what is supposed to cause `bounce_height > minimum_height` to stop being true?

Comment: Variables don't automatically update their values (that's what functions are for.) You need to put the `bounce_height` calculations  inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `bounce_height` variable outside the loop and then **update** it inside the loop. Here's an example of that (not sure if this is the exact result you want):

```py
def bounce_counter (drop_height, minimum_height, energy_loss):
    bounce = 0
    bounce_height = drop_height
    # number_of_bounces = bounce - 1
    while bounce_height > minimum_height:
        print("bounce " + str(bounce_height))
        bounce_height = drop_height*(energy_loss**bounce)
        bounce = bounce + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
  bounce_counter(2, 0.1, 0.5)
```